# Can a Servlet Filter capture the response of a URL that came from a same Host?

Tags: java, servlets

Ok, we have an web app with the following domain:

```
mydomain.com/#article;articleID=1
```

Now we have a servlet filter `mydomain.com/MyFilter`

```
public class CrawlServlet implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String fullURLQueryString = getFullURL(httpRequest);

           // here we can read mydomain.com/#article;articleID=1
           // if we open this mydomain.com/#article;articleID=1 we can see the article data that was taken from DB
           // can we somehow capture that article data?
    }

}
```

Can we be able to achieve that?

I want to do that cos I want to show the data to Bot Crawler for indexing my page.

Answer (score 0):

yes, using `URL` and `URLConnection` :

```
URL url = new URL(fullURLQueryString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```

then read page from `in`.

Comment: i tried, it just shows the html code but my article data is embedded inside javascript so i can't see it

Comment: we need solution that read the response & thus we can capture the data called from server